# Error: "Failure to find application" on launch

Tags: mac, macos

This morning I got the following error message on launch. I have not removed any applications since last launch. Google did not help.

[image: Failure to find application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seams that I have resolved it myself.

I have installed Mountain Duck, but forgot to move it to the applications folder. So the helper app for the launch on login was not able to find it and showed up this unspecific error message.